# Magento 2 showing notification again and again even after page refresh

Tags: magento2.3

**Magento2**

Notification is showing again and again even after page refresh while should show only one time and should hide on page refresh.

**Please anybody can help to fix this.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello Vijay**

Put this code on **message.js**

```
     return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: []
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        $('#validation-login-cust').html('');
        $('#valid-promo-cart').html('');
        try {
            var message = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            var textMessage =  JSON.parse(message[0]["text"]);
            if (textMessage['type'] === "inline"){
                $(textMessage["selector"]).text(textMessage["message"]).css('color', 'red');
            }

            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            customerData.set('messages', {messages: ""});
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');

        }catch (e) {

            $('#validation-login-cust').html('');
            $('#valid-promo-cart').html('');
            var messageText = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text')[_.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text').length-1];
            if (messageText) {
                if (messageText["text"].trim() == "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.") {
                    this.cookieMessages = 'OOps! Something went wrong, Please try again later or refresh the page.';
                } else {
                    this.cookieMessages = messageText;
                }
            }
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }
        }
        var setCookieInterval = setInterval(function()
        {
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            YX_UI_UTIL.eraseCookie("mage-messages");

        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(setCookieInterval); }, 10000);
    }
});
```

**Please use this code, your issue will be resolved:)**

If you find this usefull please vote and accept the Answer

Thanks

Comment: Hi Munesh, Please explain where should i write this script?

Comment: you can put this code on message.js

Comment: It works, thank you

Comment: You are Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for this post. I tried your code and not works in my Magento 2.4.4 version. What is wrong?

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: []
        },
        
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        
            $('#validation-login-cust').html('');
            $('#valid-promo-cart').html('');
            try {
                var message = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
                var textMessage =  JSON.parse(message[0]["text"]);
                if (textMessage['type'] === "inline"){
                    $(textMessage["selector"]).text(textMessage["message"]).css('color', 'red');
                }
        
                this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                    disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
                });
        
                if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                    customerData.set('messages', {});
                }
        
                customerData.set('messages', {messages: ""});
                $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        
            }catch (e) {
        
                $('#validation-login-cust').html('');
                $('#valid-promo-cart').html('');
                var messageText = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text')[_.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text').length-1];
                if (messageText) {
                    if (messageText["text"].trim() == "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.") {
                        this.cookieMessages = 'OOps! Something went wrong, Please try again later or refresh the page.';
                    } else {
                        this.cookieMessages = messageText;
                    }
                }
                this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                    disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
                });
                if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                    customerData.set('messages', {});
                }
            }
            var setCookieInterval = setInterval(function()
            {
                $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
                YX_UI_UTIL.eraseCookie("mage-messages");
        
            }, 3000);
            setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(setCookieInterval); }, 10000);
        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```